# Was using index.php but now need index.html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm learning all this web programming stuff after years writing .EXE Windows programs so bear with me.
I developed a basic .php and mysql website that works fine.

But I went to add javascript code to my index.php and I don't think the javascript code is executing.

My index.php has the form:

```
<?php

   require_once blah blah

   call_my_php_functionBlah();

?>
```

Then I added this code inside the php blocks of the '<\?\php' and "\?>" as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // some known-good javascript code that displays an image
</script>
```

Nothing showed up.
So I thought "ah-HAH, I blew it, all I need to do is -- move the javascript code *outside*
of the php block, at the bottom of index.php, and surely I'm good to go."

And still, Nothing showed up.

I checked the source of my 'known-good' javascript code and it said 'embed this javascript code
in your HTML file' so I thought "wow, I guess I need an index.html or something here."

So my questions:

1) should my index.php be able to run the javascript block of code?
   I'm guessing 'No because index.php executes on the *server* and javascript runs on the *client* machine.'

2) How should I architect this if I want to keep my index.php, whose code works fine and I don't want to mess with it?

I'm thinking that this is an *extremely basic* client/server, php and javascript script organization issue that every web programmer knows how to handle, but like I said, I'm new to all this.  I read in the archives about .htaccess etc. etc. but I
bet there's an easier way, and I'm not sure if the stuff I read applies.

Comment: The problem is not that it is a php file as you can have a php file act exactly like an html file by simply not including any php

Comment: 1. the extention .php does not affect your javascript. 2 show how u implemented the js in your page

Comment: When the client gets the output, it's all HTML - so yes, it will run javascript. Can you link to the page in question? Have you tried any basic javascript debugging tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- the file name extension is completely irrelevant
- PHP executes on the server and doesn't care at all about any Javascript
- code inside `<?php ?>` tags must of course be valid PHP code to be executed by PHP
- your browser receives whatever the result of your PHP execution is
- you can use PHP code to output Javascript or simply have Javascript on the same page outside of `<?php ?>` tags
- only whatever the browser receives matters, so use View Source
- look at the browser's Javascript Console to debug client-side Javascript problems

Answer (score 3):

```
Then I added this code inside the php blocks of the '" as follows:
```

Dont add your script inside the php block bring it outside php block.

After you are done with script you can reopen php block and write php again

Answer (score 3):

index.php can run javascript, just that You need to echo the javascript code to put it in the page.

Comment: Or even better just leave it outside the php <? ?> blocks as echoing can get messy

Comment: hmm, ya, but sometimes you need to configure js on the run with variable in php. So in these I think echoing is necessary

Comment: I use something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="<? echo $url ?>/inc/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Actually for me, this seems messy. You could try
    `<?php $script=<<<SCRIPT
               <script type="text/javascript" src="$url/inc/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
SCRIPT;
echo $script; ?> `

Answer (score 3):

Anything that appears inside your php open/close tags has to be echoed or printed to be rendered to the html page. Anything outside your php open/close tags should appear in your html page but whether it works correctly or not is another matter not necessarily related to your php. The php interpreter doesn't run your javascript code, however, so it can't just sit inside your php tags.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript will run inside .php file.

But you have to write outside the  tags.

Eg:
    index.php

```
<?php 

  echo "Helloooooo";

?>

<script>

function TestingMyFirstScript()
{
    alert(1)
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript will execute in a PHP file but not inside of a PHP block. It executes in the server, yes and anything coming from PHP should be printed out to see. You should have the JS code outside of the PHP block and it can be anywhere in the page e.g.

It depends how to mix/match the code but of course keep it clean and easy to read (and debug).

```
<?php
// code here
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
// JS here
</script>

<?php
// some more code here
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer to both of your question is that you dont have to create a separate html file to execute your JS code. You can have HTML, JS, and PHP code in the same file. PHP code inside the PHP tags will be processed on the server and replace with HTML. The server generated HTML will be combined with other HTML present on the .php file and sent to the browser as one HTML.

There must be some error in the JS code which is causing the script to fail.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

   require_once blah blah

   call_my_php_functionBlah();

?>


<script type="text/javascript">
  // some known-good javascript code that displays an image
</script>


<?php
  // other php code
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the above comments should help you with your PHP + JS problem. However, if you are still getting errors with your output, try using:

```
alert("breakpoint 1");
```

`//some code`

`alert("breakpoint 2");`

throughout your Javascript function (it will show you where the code is failing). Good for beginners debugging. Also check out http://www.jslint.com/